# How to install/run Jupyter in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: python, jupyter

I already have python3/ipython3 (and notebook) installed. So I [followed the instructions](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html), and I did:

```
$ pip3 install jupyter
```

And it seems to have succeeded. But at nothing seems installed (at least not in my PATH):

```
$ jupyter
jupyter: command not found

$ python3 jupyter
python3: can't open file 'jupyter': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

$ ipython3 jupyter
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: 'jupyter'

$ ipython jupyter
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: u'jupyter'
```

Sorry, I'm a noob when it comes to the python installation details, I'm certainly missing something obvious, but I can't find it in the docs.

Any help would be much appreciated!! :)

Comment: Just after I asked I went back to use ipython notebook that I was using before, and I got: 

    $ ipython3 notebook
    [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
    [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook`... continue in 5 sec. Press Ctrl-C to quit now.
    ...

Odd ... still, jupyter is not found in my PATH.

Comment: Is it in ~/.local/bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to debug another issue with installing a Golang kernel (gophernotes), I found out it is installed in `${HOME}/.local/bin/jupyter`.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

Jupyter Notebook is replacing IPython Notebook as the most commonly used web-based interactive computational environment for creating IPython notebooks.

[image]

Starting in Ubuntu 17.04 Jupyter Notebook can be installed directly from the default Ubuntu repositories (`sudo apt install jupyter-notebook jupyter-core python-ipykernel` in Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10). python-ipykernel is necessary for running Python 2.x programs in Jupyter Notebook, which otherwise supports only Python 3.x.

#### Install Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu 20.04 and later

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install jupyter-notebook jupyter
```

#### Install Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu 18.04-19.10

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-notebook jupyter jupyter-core python-ipykernel
```

python-ipykernel is necessary for running Python 2.x programs in Jupyter Notebook, which otherwise supports only Python 3.x.

To start the notebook server run the following command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

You should see Jupyter Notebook open in your web browser.

#### Install Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu 14.04→16.10

The following instructions are for installing Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu 14.04→16.10. The default version of Python in Ubuntu works OK, but pip needs to be updated to the latest version.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install python-pip python-dev
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
sudo apt -y install ipython ipython-notebook
pip install --user jupyter
```

To start the notebook server run the following command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

You should see Jupyter Notebook open in your web browser.

If you also have python-matplotlib installed, the first line of code to enable plotting in the current Notebook is `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: It seemed to me the point of this question - and the question *I* have - is that after `apt-get install jupyter` the executable is *nowhere to be found*